# Is it possible to get all the connections made to the database by Npgsql?

Tags: c#, postgresql, npgsql

If possible, i would like to get all the connections made by Npgsql to the PostgreSql database. 
And in turn, select a particular connection based on its PID.

Comment: You can find out which connections there are currently, for example from pg_stat_activity, and it has a column `application_name`

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen Is it not possible to get the NpgsqlConnection object reference of all the connections from c# ?

Answer (score 0):

Npgsql tracks all connections in use internally in its connection pool, but this isn't exposed to the user in any way. You could track the NpgsqlConnection objects you create in your own code outside of Npgsql.

Once you have NpgsqlConnection instances, you can get the backend process ID with the ProcessID property.